# Invoke different entrypoints/modules when training with custom container

Tags: google-cloud-ml, gcp-ai-platform-training, google-ai-platform

I've built a custom Docker container with my training application. The Dockerfile, at the moment, is something like

```
FROM python:slim
COPY ./src /pipelines/component/src
RUN pip3 install -U ...
...
ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "/pipelines/component/src/training.py"]
```

so when I run

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training JOB_NAME \
--region=$REGION \
--master-image-uri=$IMAGE_URI
```

it goes as expected.

What I'd like to do is to add another module, like `/pipelines/component/src/tuning.py`; remove the default `ENTRYPOINT` from Dockerfile; decide which module to call from the `gcloud` command. So I tried

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training JOB_NAME \
--region=$REGION \
--master-image-uri=$IMAGE_URI \
--module-name=src.tuning \
--package-path=/pipelines/component/src
```

It returns `Source directory [/pipelines/component] is not a valid directory.`, because it's searching for the package path on the local machine, instead of the container. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [TrainingInput.ReplicaConfig.ContainerCommand](https://ml.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v1) field to override the docker image's entrypoint. Here is a sample command:

```
gcloud ai-platform jobs submit training JOB_NAME \
--region=$REGION
--master-image-uri=$IMAGE_URI
--config=config.yaml
```

And config.yaml content will be something like this:

```
trainingInput:
  scaleTier: BASIC
  masterConfig:
    containerCommand: ["python3", "/pipelines/component/src/tuning.py"]
```

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/ai-platform/jobs/submit/training#--config) has more context about config flag.

Similarly, you can override docker image's command with **containerArgs** field.

Comment: Your solution works and I upvote it. The problem is: the `containerArgs` I should pass are dinamically assigned in the shell script that launches the tuning job. Is there a way to pass these arguments at the `config.yaml` file during execution? Or can I specify `containerCommand/Args` directly in the `gcloud` command?